# Gemini API returns as list instead of a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to write a program using the Gemini public API but when I use requests to fetch the JSON page I get a list instead of a dictionary with searchable key pairs. What am I doing wrong/missing in my code? I want to be able to pull out 1 key pair such as the ETHUSD key pair.

````
import requests

raw_prices = requests.get("https://api.gemini.com/v1/pricefeed")
format_prices = raw_prices.json()
print(format_prices)
print(type(format_prices))```
````

Answer (score 0):

according to the doc you need to do the following call:

```
GET https://api.gemini.com/v2/ticker/:symbol
```

Using ethusd as symbol so it looks like:

```
https://api.gemini.com/v2/ticker/ethusd
```

I don't think you can get some data like open/high/low or even an array of the last price changes in 24h.

You can read more [here](https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#ticker-v2) on the official doc.

Comment: this api call: https://api.gemini.com/v1/pricefeed gets the current prices of a lot of crypto indexes I just want to be able to pull the price of one of them like ETHUSD

Comment: @SamuelRubinstein check my answer use /v2/ticker/ethusd instead